# How can I move the column into row to get the age range?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm doing the reports for my project. And I want to get the range of age of all the beneficiary. I did it but the problem is the age range is on the column. I want to put it on the row. Can somebody help me with my problem?

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - 
    DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < 
    DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '00-%m-%d')) BETWEEN 18 and 24,1,0)) as '18 - 24',
    SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - 
    DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < 
    DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '00-%m-%d')) BETWEEN 25 and 34,1,0)) as '25 - 34',
    SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - 
    DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < 
    DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '00-%m-%d')) BETWEEN 35 and 44,1,0)) as '35 - 44'
FROM tbl_beneficiary
```

This is the output of the query above

```
Output 

18-24   25-34   35-44  ...
  1       0       0
```

I want this to be the result

```
Age     Total
18-24     1
25-34     0
35-44     0
...
```

Comment: you can use **case** expression for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're interested in zero counts as well, you could build (or generate) a table of range brackets and `LEFT JOIN` with it. Rough outline of query (does not use the correct method of age calculation):

```
SELECT brackets.lbl, COUNT(t.id)
FROM (
    SELECT 0  AS a, 17 AS b, '<18' AS lbl UNION ALL 
    SELECT 18,      24,      '18-24'      UNION ALL
    SELECT 25,      34,      '25-34'      UNION ALL
    SELECT 35,      44,      '35-44'      UNION ALL
    SELECT 45,      999,     '45+'
) AS brackets
LEFT JOIN t ON YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(birth_date) BETWEEN a and b
GROUP BY brackets.lbl
```

Comment: Can you give me an example table for range brackets? I don't have any idea

Comment: You don't need the table (in the above example I _generated_ it using UNION ALL). You can create a physical table based on the above example.

Comment: It works! I just change the value inside the COUNT()

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when birthdate > now() - interval 18 year then 'Under 18'
             when birthdate > now() - interval 25 year then '18 - 24'
             when birthdate > now() - interval 35 year then '25 - 34'
             . . .
         end) as age_group,
        count(*)
from t
group by age_group
order by birthdate;
```

Comment: I'm shocked to discover I'm in age bracket a whole decade ahead of where I thought :-(

Comment: Why it gives me a null value in  'Under 18' of age_group and the 25-34 is not showing at all